# How to change formatting of Html.DisplayFor for a user-defined class in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My main model, Project, has a property called "ProjectAddress" which is of type "Address"--a class that I defined. Address has the properties Line1, Line2, City, State, and ZipCode. When I use `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectAddress)`, it displays as:

```
Line 1
<Line1 value here>
Line 2
<Line2 value here>
City
<City value here>
...
```

and so on. I would like it to display as:

```
<Line 1>
<Line 2 if defined>
<City>, <State>, <ZipCode>
<County> County
```

without the property headers above each value. I can do this manually each time I want to display the address by hard coding

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectAddress.Line1)
@if (!String.IsEmptyOrNull(model.ProjectAddress.Line2))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectAddress.Line2)
}
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectAddress.City), @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectAddress.State), @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectAddress.ZipCode)
```

but that's very tedious and if I change the format of my address class for whatever reason I'll have to go through my code and change each instance of that. Is there a way that I can change the formatting of `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectAddress)` to be the block of code above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a custom display template. Add the file, `Views\Shared\DisplayTemplates\Address.cshtml`, and put the following code inside:

```
@model Namespace.To.Address
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Line1)
@if (!String.IsEmptyOrNull(Model.Line2))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Line2)
}
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.City), @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.State), 
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ZipCode)
```

Then, you can use `DisplayFor` as you tried originally in your view:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ProjectAddress)
```

Razor will use the template you defined to render the `ProjectAddress` instance.

Comment: Just as an FYI to anyone reading this, make sure you change `Namespace.To.Address` to your actual fully qualified object name (name plus namespace)

Answer (score 1):

Check out a thing called Display Templates. The short of it is this..

1. You create a new folder under `views/shared` called 'DisplayTemplates` (you can also have editor templates.
2. Add a new cshtml file called `Address.cshtml`. Set its model to `My.LongNamespace.Address`
3. Add the code you want to use to 'mark-up' the address type.

### Example Address.cshtml (untested)

```
@model My.LongNamespace.Address

@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Line1)
@if (!String.IsEmptyOrNull(model.Line2))
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Line2)
}
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City), 
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.State), 
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ZipCode)
```